# How to use json2html with jquery within Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, json2html

I'm tasked with integrating an existing UI into another already existing Angular app and got hung up on this...

I know the data + transform works well outside of the Angular context.

I didn't see an npm package for the jquery json2html so I tried to import that part in an ad-hoc manner by saving it along side the component's directory.

It produces `ERROR TypeError: $(...).json2html is not a function...`

```
...
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import json2html from 'json2html';
import * from './jquery.json2html.min.js';

...

$('#myTable > tbody').json2html(data,transform);
```

Comment: Using jQuery within Angular is generally seen as an anti-pattern

Comment: Honestly, this feels like something that could be done _super simply_ with standard Angular patterns, without the need for any sort of library....

Comment: Why don't you use jspdf(and maybe html2canvas) in angular? [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-using-angular-6/)'s a guide with an example. I've used this in angular 6 and it's worked like a charm

Comment: @user184994 that's why I included the context about integrating two separate applications.  The goal is to get this done, even if it's dirty.

Comment: @RaySoy no I don't want PDFs. I want an interactive HTML table within the DOM.

Comment: @cale_b Sounds great. How?

Answer (score 0):

```
    npm install node-json2html


    ...
    import json2html from 'json2html';
    import * as $ from 'node-json2html';

    ...

ngAfterViewInit(){
    $('table#myTable > tbody').json2html(data,transform);

}
```

or,

```
... 
import json2html from 'json2html';
import * as $ from './jquery.json2html.min.js';

...

$('table#myTable > tbody').json2html(data,transform);
```

Link:-  http://www.json2html.com/

Comment: This will cause errors, you've already imported jquery as `*`, and doing `declare const $:any;` will clash with the previous declaration

Comment: This doesn't work. You're squashing the jquery import like @user184994 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

before anything you have to add `jQuery` in your `angular.json` then in the component you would to use *jQuery* with it do so

```
....
declare let $: any;    // you can use "jQuery" keyword instead of "$"

@component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: ['...'],
  styleUrls: ['...']
})
export class JqueryExampleComponent implements onInit {

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.eleRef.nativeElement).find('#myTable > tbody').json2html(data,transform);
  }
}
```

when you use `$(this.eleRef.nativeElement)` that gonna get the *tree root* of the `component` dom then `.find('selector')` to get the `element` you want

Comment: The problem here is that `json2html` is somehow not in scope, not that I can't perform selections using jquery.